# Display colours with tput command strings

Tags: bash

I have the following bash functions that return the `tput` command string.

```
firefly_tput ()
 {
   return "tput bold ; tput setaf 218"
 }

firefly_sgr0 ()
 {
   return "tput sgr0"
 }
```

I then set the variable

```
klr="$( firefly_tput )" 
rst="$( firefly_sgr0 )"
```

so that I can do

```
printf "%b%s%b" "$klr" "HELLO" "$rst"
```

But I cannot display the coloured text as I had hoped.

Comment: `return` ?  That's not how `return` works,  at least in my shell, see `help return`

Answer (score 0):

A function is not needed/required for your task, a Command Substitution should suffice, something like:

```
klr="$(tput bold ; tput setaf 218)"
rst="$(tput sgr0)"
```

```
printf "%s%s%s\n" "$klr" "HELLO" "$rst"
```

---

- `return` requires a numeric/int argument not a string. According to `help return`

Comment: Then, I would need to use a direct `printf "%s\n" "tput bold ; tput setaf 218"`.

Comment: Inside the function? No need? `tput` is a command, and that command need to be executed, not just print to `STDOUT`

Comment: Still the colour does not get activated whet doing `printf "%s%s%s\n" "$klr" "HELLO" "$rst"`

Comment: My solution works as expected, not sure what you have in your shell, or settings/config files, or do you even use `bash` as your shell?

Comment: I am using bash and getting the string printed as `tput bold ; tput setaf 196 ;  HELLO`

Comment: Put the code above in a script and execute it, does it makes a difference?

Comment: If I do `firefly-tput` I get the printed string `tput bold ; tput setaf 218 ;`.  But if I use `red="$( firefly-tput )" ` in terminal, the colour does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the functions

```
#! /bin/bash


firefly_tput () {
   tput bold ; tput setaf 218
}

firefly_sgr0 () {
   tput sgr0
}


printf "%s%s%s\n" "$(firefly_tput)" "HELLO" "$(firefly_sgr0)"
```

Comment: Would you know, given the command in a string, how to get it to execute?

Comment: Why would you have it in a string, perhaps the color `tput setaf "$color"`

Comment: Because I am constructing some complicated commands, with the final composite command stored in a string.  Meaning that the same function could be used for constructing different `tput` commands, rather than just a single one, as in your examples.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never store commands in a string as the complex cases would be a problem